# Symfony form panel not showing in profiler

Tags: symfony, panel, missing-features

I'm upgrading an old app in symfony 3.1 which was missing the forms panel after "Validation" panel on the left (it's the only missing panel). I thought that upgrading to latest 3.4.x (currently 3.4.18) would solve the problem. I've even deleted the whole vendor tree and installed from composer, but I don't get it to be on the web profiler though I see the "new" green bar and the version.

Any new projects or created by myself have it, so I don't think it's anything related to my installation. I've even compared composer.json to try to find out what could be missing, but I was unable to find anything useful. And the .../view/Collectors/form.html.twig file is there.

Here is my AppKernel.php:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function __construct($environment, $debug)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
    }

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
            new Vich\UploaderBundle\VichUploaderBundle(),
            new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
            new Ikadoc\KCFinderBundle\IkadocKCFinderBundle(),
            new Core23\DompdfBundle\Core23DompdfBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
       $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot at login page, where there is a form:
[image: screenshot at login page]

What am I missing?

Comment: What are your bundles, framework, and routing configurations for your dev environment?

Comment: Well, I think that pasting such contents is too expensive for this question. Could you tell me something more specific to look for?

Comment: Since you already attempted updating Symfony and clearing the vendor files. It points to your specific application configuration settings for Symfony. Which determine what is enabled/disabled in the Symfony profiler. We can't help without knowing your configuration, as it would just be a guessing game.  And since there were significant non-BC changes from 3.1 to 3.4, there is a lot that could have gone wrong.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain clearly. I have a running branch in 3.1, and I have another branch with the test and everything to upgrade to 3.4, so I have more than one branch. Neither has the form panel, and I'm not aware of anything going wrong. For other reasons, one of the test to try to be a "clean" install in an empty machine, I also tried to do "composer install" with a copy of the 3.4 branch without the vendor tree. Also, I think that you want to see the AppKernel.php file, so I'll add it above.

Comment: We would need to see your `/app/config/` settings for your framework, and routing  as they control how your  Symfony application is configured. Your `AppKernel` will load the bundles, which determine what core Symfony bundles are used/available in your application, that can also be configured, such as the `WebProfilerBundle`. Since you cleaned out the `vendor` directory and presumably not made changes to the files that are managed by composer, it would more than likely not be related to the Symfony installation, but your specific Symfony configuration.

Comment: You can compare the values in the `app/config/` and `<bundle>/Resources/config` configurations from a working application, and the one that is not working, to determine which setting might be disabled that is causing you the issue.

Comment: I've checked all the files in app/config/ and though there were small differences and I've copied it all, I still see no difference. Does anybody know what are the requirements for this exact panel to be shown?

Comment: Just to make sure; when the panel is not showing, are you on a page that renders a Symfony form? Symfony will hide the panel when no Symfony forms are rendered. You can click the debugger and the `Forms` section will report: `No forms were submitted for this request.`

Comment: I've just added a screenshot at login, where there is a form. In other apps and AFAICT, regardless there's a form or not, the form panel always shows up, and is enabled or not depending only on the form contents.

Comment: Please update your question with the output from the command `php bin/console debug:config framework`